# What is the best way to save Likes/Favorites /Comments/Follows in a MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to learn MongoDB from a photography website. On this page, each image is assigned to a location. Each location can have many images from different users.

Currently I have three collections. users, spots (for the locations) and spotimages.

What I'm trying to do now:
 - Users should be able to like images.
 - Users should be able to add spots to their own favorites (in the end also a like, but the favorites should only be shown in the user's profile).
 - Users should be able to comment on spots and pictures.
 - Users should be able to follow other users as well as individual spots.

Where do I save the most efficient Likes / Favorites / Comments / Follows?
On the Document the User want to like or on the User document it self.

I think, both will work (why not?) but what is the most efficient? Or is there a totaly differen way to do that better?

I have also read about own collections for likes/comments/etc. But on other pages you can read that this would not be the optimal way. I've googled the problem many times and you always get different recommendations. So it would be nice to know why one or the other variant is faster/better.

Currently I have in the collection spotimages an array with objects. Each object contains the userID and a date. Additionally I save the number of Likes separately (also in the spotimages collection) and increase or decrease them with each change by 1.

```
if(alreadyLiked == true){

    const imageLikedBy = { "userId": userId }
    const interaction = await SpotImage.updateOne( { _id: interactionInput.id }, { $pull: { likedBy: imageLikedBy }, $inc: { likes: -1 } } )

    return interaction

}else{

    const imageLikedBy = { "userId": userId, "datetime": new Date() }
    const interaction = await SpotImage.updateOne( { _id: interactionInput.id }, { $push: { likedBy: imageLikedBy }, $inc: { likes: 1 } } )

    return interaction

}
```

```
{
    "_id":"5c89241f40e5b33da6a979ea",
    "ownedBy":"5c5d7339f49e124ce6ceb63f",
    [...]
    "likedBy":[{
        "userId":"5cacfa79bcd8614feb52e085",
    "datetime":"2019-04-10T20:43:06.369Z"
    }],
    "likes":1
}
```

I save the favorites according to the same logic. But in the spots collection.
Comments & Follows doesn't exist right now in my project, but they will in the future and there for I have the same Question...

One sample document of each of my collections:

users:

```
{
    "_id":"5c5d7339f49e124ce6ceb63f",
    "firstname":"...",
    "surname":"...",
    "username":"...",
    "email":"mail@....com",
    "password":"..",
    "img_name":"...",
    "createdAt":"2019-02-08T12:16:57.658Z",
    "updatedAt":"2019-04-13T16:19:52.351Z",
    "__v":0,
    "description":"...",
    "access":"9",
    "social":{
        "website":"https://....com",
        "facebook":"https://facebook.com/...",
        "instagram":"https://www.instagram.com/...",
        "youtube":"https://youtube.com/channel/..."
    }
}
```

spots:

```
{
    "_id":"5c925c32db973e4224dae9eb",
    "location":{
        "coordinates":[10.749331,47.579609],
        "type":"Point"
    },
    "hashtags":[...],
    "modifiedBy":[{
        "userId":"5c9257eddb973e4224dae9ea",
        "typ":"created",
        "datetime":"2019-03-20T15:28:50.781Z"
    }],
    "name":"St. Coloman",
    "description":"A small but very special and unique church in front of impressive mountains.",
    "photography_tips":"Best spot for taking a picture is In front of the church about 100 meters away.",
    "access_information":"The village is named \"Schwangau\". You will find the church on your way to the castle.",
    "address":"St. Coloman, 95, Colomanstraße, Horn, Schwangau, Landkreis Ostallgäu, Swabia, Bavaria, 87645, Germany",
    "createdAt":"2019-03-20T15:28:50.782Z",
    "updatedAt":"2019-04-13T20:30:19.308Z",
    "__v":0,
    "favoriteBy":[{
        "userId":"5c5d7339f49e124ce6ceb63f",
        "datetime":"2019-04-13T20:30:19.308Z"
    }],
    "favorites":1
}
```

spotimages:

```
{
    "_id":"5c925c32db973e4224dae9ec",
    "hashtags":[...],
    "file_name":"f4048202b540cd0d2b810c7a1242a684",
    "name":"LRM_EXPORT_192313666969612_20190119_202136264.jpeg",
    "spotId":"5c925c32db973e4224dae9eb",
    "ownedBy":"5c9257eddb973e4224dae9ea",
    "createdAt":"2019-03-20T15:28:50.784Z",
    "updatedAt":"2019-04-09T10:17:34.046Z",
    "__v":0,
    "likedBy":[{
        "userId":"5c5d7339f49e124ce6ceb63f",
        "datetime":"2019-04-09T10:17:34.045Z"
    }],
    "likes":1
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you please share a sample document from each of your existing collections? It would be helpful to understand your structure. "Where do I save the most efficient Likes / Comments? On the Document the User want to like or on the User document it self." - This will depend on which document is being primarily acted upon. If it's the image, store the likes and comments as an additional field in the image document.

Comment: @SubhashreePradhan Thank you very much for the quick answer. I have added sample documents from the three collections. "store the likes and comments as an additional field in the image document" - I have also read a few times that you should make your own collections for it. You would also simply attach it to the document? And think about which one you have to access more often? Sounds right to me, or that's how I would have done it, I'm just not sure if there are any "better" ways, because I'm totally new to MongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question comes down to the point, as to which of these entities (users, spots & spot-images) is your primary entity.
There are two types of data models, used in MongoDB -

1. **Embedded/Denormalized Data Model** - In general, embedded data models are used when:

   - you have “contains” relationships between entities.
   - you have one-to-many relationships between entities. In these relationships the “many” or child documents always appear with or are viewed in the context of the “one” or parent documents.
2. **Normalized Data Model** - Your separate collections structure comes under this data model. This is used :

   - when embedding would result in duplication of data but would not provide sufficient read performance advantages to outweigh the implications of the duplication.
   - to represent more complex many-to-many relationships.

For reference, please refer this link :
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/

---

Example : Let's consider, you have the spot-image as the primary entity. But when you are displaying that image, you are also fetching the names of the users who liked/commented on it, it's better to store images and users in an embedded document structure.

But if embedding is resulting in duplication of data, I would recommend you to continue the normalized structure that you are following.